# tcpmon Java Axis2 client web service response being redirected

Tags: java, soap, apache-axis

I used Eclipse Indigo on Windows7 to generate Axis2 (Axis 1.6.1 JDK compliance 1.5) java stubs and successfully called the public web service at http://www.xmlme.com/WSShakespeare.asmx?WSDL
Got perfect response to getSpeech method of said service. Then I used tcpmon (plugin) to see xml being exchanged. Added Listen port = 4556, Target Host name = www.xmlme.com and Target port = 80 This generated HTTP 302 Moved error. To recap works correctly when called with

```
ShakespeareSoapProxy ssp = new ShakespeareSoapProxy("http://www.xmlme.com:80/WSShakespeare.asmx?WSDL");
```

but fails when tcpmon listener added and called with

```
ShakespeareSoapProxy ssp = new ShakespeareSoapProxy("http://localhost:4556/WSShakespeare.asmx?WSDL");
```

tcpmon soap Request

```
POST /WSShakespeare.asmx?WSDL HTTP/1.0
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Accept: application/soap+xml, application/dime, multipart/related, text/*
User-Agent: Axis/1.4
Host: www.xmlme.com:4556
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
SOAPAction: "http://xmlme.com/WebServices/GetSpeech"
Content-Length: 359

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><soapenv:Body><GetSpeech xmlns="http://xmlme.com/WebServices"><Request>To be, or not to be</Request></GetSpeech></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
---------tcpmon response below----------------------------
HTTP/1.0 302 Moved
Location: http://172.16.1.6:15871/cgi-bin/blockpage.cgi?ws-session=1096295497
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

Why is tcpmon failing as above is my primary question. WHY did I tcpmon it when the SOAP client worked perfectly? Because I generated a jar out of it and it worked great on Windows7. But when I ran the same jar on my iSeries aka AS400 server it gave me Axis fault HTTP 401 unauthorized & Authentication required message. Our IT guys do run websense to block stuff but this is localhost on windows client where I have run .NET web services before. Ideas, responses are **greatly** appreciated, thanks.

Edit - Some research points at NTLM default credentials that windows sends and server doesnt? Anyone want to comment if that could be it?

Answer (score 0):

The IP you're being redirected to (172.16.1.6) is local to your network (see ["Reserved IP addresses"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reserved_IP_addresses).) Check with your network administrators whether they're blocking your request to www.xmlme.com and why.

It looks to me like the problem should reproduce without tcpmon as well. You can use a network sniffer (e.g. [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/)) to compare the traffic with and without tcpmon.

Comment: Eli - Thanks! I could not vote you up as I dont have enough reputation LOL. Sadly there is NO problem simply direct calling it from Win7 (port 80), works great! Introducing tcpmon & port 4556 causes the problem. Also baffling is that even direct calling works in Win7 and fails with HTTP 401 unauthorized on server (non windows AS400 / iSeries). Some research points at NTLM default credentials that windows sends and server doesnt? Anyone want to comment if that could be it?

Comment: Glad to help (although apparently I was wrong, as you say tcpmon _does_ make a difference :-)).
IMHO a sniffer can help you see the difference between the requests that succeed and those that fail.
I suggest you add the new information (regarding NTLM etc.) to the body of the question - it will improve your chances of getting answers.

Comment: Thanks Eli, I will edit post for NTLM, I will also try and check out this wireshark, tcpmon could not intercept, maybe that will!